# Qt Vertical Scroll bar stylesheets

Tags: qt

[image: Could you pls give me code snippets for styling scroll bar as show in the attached image.]]

Could you pls give me code snippets for styling scroll bar as show in the attached image
thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("QScrollBar:vertical {"              
    "    border: 1px solid #999999;"
    "    background:white;"
    "    width:10px;    "
    "    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"
    "}"
    "QScrollBar::handle:vertical {"
    "    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,"
    "    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));"
    "    min-height: 0px;"
    "}"
    "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {"
    "    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,"
    "    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));"
    "    height: 0px;"
    "    subcontrol-position: bottom;"
    "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
    "}"
    "QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {"
    "    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,"
    "    stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));"
    "    height: 0 px;"
    "    subcontrol-position: top;"
    "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
    "}"
    ));
```

Comment: While I like the answer, I don't understand the usage of a gradient for generating the same RGB value. Could you explain why this was done?

Comment: Background for "add-line" and "sub-line" are useless as height is set to 0 (they are completely hidden)

Comment: Not rounded as requested.