# How to set different heights for pages( add-page,sub-page) and arrows(left,right) in QScrollBar?

Tags: qt, height, scrollbar

[Scrollbar with different Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGrL.png)

I would like to set different  heights  for pages and arrows in the scrollbar.

Example : page height :25 px, arrow height:30 handle height:30

Image attached

Comment: Please add more information on what you are looking for?
Probably a sketch will help on what kind of GUI you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scrollBar->setStyleSheet(...)` starting from [this information](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar)
and search for examples, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438095/qt-vertical-scroll-bar-stylesheets/12639369#12639369)