# Change qt scrollbar style to match default qml scrollbar

Tags: qt, scrollbar, stylesheet

How can I have the same style for qt scrollbars than the default one on qml?

Here is a screenshot of the default scrollbar on qt:
[image]

And this is the one with qml ScollView component.
[image]

Comment: Ok, so I found the answer in another post... thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438095/qt-vertical-scroll-bar-stylesheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround, using stylesheet.

```
    this->setStyleSheet(QString(
        "QScrollBar:vertical {"
        "    border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;"
        "    background: transparent;"
        "    width: 13px;    "
        "    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar:horizontal {"
        "    border: 0px solid #c6c6c6;"
        "    background: transparent;"
        "    height: 13px;    "
        "    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar::handle {"
        "    background: #c6c6c6;"
        "    border: 3px solid %1;"
        "    border-radius: 6px;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {"
        "    height: 0px;"
        "    subcontrol-position: bottom;"
        "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {"
        "    height: 0 px;"
        "    subcontrol-position: top;"
        "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {"
        "    width: 0px;"
        "    subcontrol-position: right;"
        "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
        "}"
        "QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {"
        "    width: 0 px;"
        "    subcontrol-position: left;"
        "    subcontrol-origin: margin;"
        "}").arg(SUPER_LIGHT_GREY));
```