# PyQt style QComboBox drop down border color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, stylesheet, qcombobox

I am trying to remove the grey border that surrounds the drop down of a QComboBox.

[image: screenshot of drop down]

I have attempted to use this style sheet to no avail:

```
self.combobox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{color: rgb(255, 149, 0 );\n"
                                        "background-color: transparent;\n"
                                        "background-image:url(background.png);}\n"
                                        "QComboBox QAbstractItemView{border: 0px;color:orange}")
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: [Customizing QScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Vertical Scroll bar stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438095/qt-vertical-scroll-bar-stylesheets)

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks, could you please also help with the border color? I have tried setting the view stylesheet however this seems to only effect what is inside of the default grey border. cheers

Comment: @eyllanesc please see above comment

Comment: @Kermit Show what you have tried, point out what you are getting by explaining what does not work.

Comment: @eyllanesc please check edit.

Comment: @Kermit: Please don't embed profanity in the image's alt text. This tripped our automated spam detection systems.

Comment: @Kermit or for that matter, don't put profanity anywhere in the post at all.  It's unnecessary and is considered 'rude' by the community at large.

Comment: @bwDraco noted.

Comment: @ekhumoro please see latest edit thanks